# Does the partner of a British national, with UK indefinite leave to remain, need a Schengen visa to travel for holidays with us?

Tags: visas, schengen

My partner is a Pakistani national with a Pakistani passport. He holds an indefinite leave to remain in the UK (permanent residence card). Does he need to apply for a Schengen visa before travelling to France or any other Schengen countries with us on holiday?

We have a son and he is the father.

Comment: @gparyani this has elements of EU family member rights which are not mentioned in the linked question

Answer (score 2):

The answer to [Does the spouse of British national with UK permanent residence need a Schengen visa to travel to France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42170/does-the-spouse-of-british-national-with-uk-permanent-residence-need-a-schengen) answers most of your question, except that you wrote "partner" and not "spouse" or "husband". If your partner is not married to you, a family visa is still possible if you can document a [durable relationship](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/family/couple/de-facto-unions/index_en.htm), but it gets slightly more complicated.